# Find and replace only certain fields in a document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo document like so:

```
{
    "_id" : "EimL8Hf5SsCQKM7WP",
    "enable" : "no",
    "collector" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "prod",
            "enable" : "no",
            "transport" : {
                "address" : {},
                "port" : "8000",
                "protocol" : "http-secure"
            },
            "authentication" : {},
            "notify-syslog" : "yes"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "test",
            "enable" : "no",
            "transport" : {
                "address" : {},
                "port" : "8000",
                "protocol" : "http-secure"
            },
            "authentication" : {},
            "notify-syslog" : "yes"
        }
    ],
   "misc" : {
        "createdBy" : "someuser",
        "updatedBy" : "someuser",
    }
}
```

I display certain fields of the mongo document [as an autoform](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform) to the user so that they can be edited. Since the other fields are hidden, the outcome of the form will only contain the fields that were exposed.

I end up with a modified document object like so: (keep an eye on the "name" fields)

```
{
    "enable" : "no",
    "collector" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "someohername",
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "anothername",
        }
    ],
    "misc" : {
        "createdBy" : "someuser",
        "updatedBy" : "anotheruser",
    }
}
```

My current requirement is to somehow merge both the documents together such that the initial document has all fields of the modified document, along with it's fields.

**Outcome:**

```
{
    "_id" : "EimL8Hf5SsCQKM7WP",
    "enable" : "no",
    "collector" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "someothername",
            "enable" : "no",
            "transport" : {
                "address" : {},
                "port" : "8000",
                "protocol" : "http-secure"
            },
            "authentication" : {},
            "notify-syslog" : "yes"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "anothername",
            "enable" : "no",
            "transport" : {
                "address" : {},
                "port" : "8000",
                "protocol" : "http-secure"
            },
            "authentication" : {},
            "notify-syslog" : "yes"
        }
    ],
   "misc" : {
        "createdBy" : "someuser",
        "updatedBy" : "anotheruser",
    }
}
```

If you notice above, only the name field has been updated whilst retaining the remaining fields.

I tried to directly update the document using `collection.update({id}, $set:{<<modified_docuemnt}});` but it is replacing the entire `collector` field with what is passed in the `$set`

How exactly do I go about this? It does not matter if I'm doing the changes directly in `mongodb` or as a `JSON` object using `javascript`.

Comment: So where is this *"processing internally"* data? In another collection? In memory?  How do we know which document to match it to? How do you know which array elements it matches to? How do you know the elements in the collection you want to "merge" to have not changed? Is there more? Is There less? So you need to be a lot more specific about **all** of those details.

Comment: I've clarified my "processing internally". Nothing fancy happening there though apart from exposing certain fields as a form to the user and getting back a form object

Comment: The catch here is the "array" elements. In your "autoform" is there something that "ties" your "name" values to the particular array elements? Maybe your example here is not a true indication since the array here shows "both" of the elements with exactly the same content. I want your **real** use case here. Because what we DO NOT want to do, is update by "index" or overwrite existing content.

Comment: Yes. The offender here is an array that contains objects. I'm trying to draft a more detailed usecase which I shall update in sometime. But what I can guarantee is that the position of the array elements will not change,so  I'm not sure on the repurcussions of updating by index if it comes down to that.

Comment: Here's the basics. You can do `"$set": { "collector.0.name": "someothername" }` which creates the property at the `0` index without overwriting everything else. **BUT** Using an exact index like this is a bad practice. Ideally we can "match" the position of the array to update by criteria instead. That's the case that you want.